# CentOS 6.5: USB or DVD option wont show in boot menu

Tags: centos, live-usb

I downloaded CentOS 6.5 - I need this version for a particular reason - liveCD and used both Win32 Disk Imager and ISO to USB to create a bootable USB. However, after rebooting and manually bring up the boot options, the USB is absent.

I even tried create a bootable DVD and still no luck.

Strangely, I get it to work with CentOS 7, but why?

How can I get CentOS 6.5 live version to work?

Comment: Are you using UEFI or Legacy boot options?

Comment: i just figured it out. I disabled secure boot and enable legacy and they now show up